# How to convert UIImage to base64 and POST to URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsdictionary

I'm having difficult with converting an image to base64 and then posting it to a server, where I will receive a number in return. I am using objective c.

Any ideas? I've tried a couple of things but I always get a thread error when trying to set certain NSDictionary parameters.

Comment: What have you tried? How is your server expecting the data? As `multipart/form-data`? Can you change the server code?
Why not just post the data as-is (as JPEG or PNG with the correct `Content-Type` header, but without base64)?

Comment: it has to be converted to base64 in order to be interpreted

Comment: Interpreted by whom? When downloading images (they are the body of the response), no base64 is used, so why would it be needed when uploading them (they are the body of the request)? Regardless: my comment was intended as an appeal to show us some code and tell us exactly where it fails (or where you’re stuck).

Comment: https://docs.indico.io/docs/rest-api-image-analysis 
well this is the website that I'm trying to use in my iOS app
to my understanding, it converts an image to a base64 string, interprets it and returns data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert UIImage in base64

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 1.0);
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
NSString *encodedString2 = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes( NULL,  (CFStringRef)base64String,    NULL,   CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),   kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

send this string using normal way and post on server. Also need to minor changes on your server to getting this image.

Comment: Unfortunately `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` is now deprecated with iOS 9 :(

Answer (score 3):

Convert UIImage to base64 string  For Objective c

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profileImgObj.image, 1.0);
NSString *base64Img = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

For Swift

```
let Imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profileImgObj.image, 0.5)
let strBase64Image = Imagedata!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres how I do it with Swift:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
let imageString = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
```